# How to send batches of URLs into grequest?

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, batch-processing, api-design, grequests

I have a list of ~300K API URLs that I want to call and get data from:

lst = ['url.com','url2.com']

If I subset my list down to say 5 urls `grequest` handles the request perfectly. However when I pass in the full ~300K URLs I get error:

```
Problem: url.Iam.passing.in: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='url', port=xxx): Max retries exceeded with url: url.Iam.passing.in (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x552b17550>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known',))
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Code so far to make the asynchronous calls:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.urls = lst

    def exception(self, request, exception):
        print ("Problem: {}: {}".format(request.url, exception))

    def async(self):
        return grequests.map((grequests.get(u, stream=False) for u in self.urls), exception_handler=self.exception, size=5)


    def collate_responses(self, results):
        return [x.text for x in results]
test = Test()
#here we collect the results returned by the async function
results = test.async()
response_text = test.collate_responses(results)
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, when I have even passed `stream=False`.

Is there anyway I can pass my list in batches?

Comment: If runtime is not a concern, try introducing a 0.5 sec lag between each request using `time.sleep(0.5)`

Comment: runtime is not a concern. But where exactly do I add it in the code?

Comment: Pass one url at a time using a for loop... something like: `for url in self.urls: async(url) time.sleep(0.5)`

Comment: @SmitM I am still not able to nail the code with your for loop. Could you please give me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something on these lines:

```
def async(x):
    #.....do something here.....#
    #return grequests.map((grequests.get(x, stream=False)), exception_handler=self.exception, size=5)

for url in url_list:
    result = async(url)
    time.sleep(5)   #This will add a 5 second delay
```